# How To Curve Road Without Array Modifier?

Tags: bezier-curves

Ok so I have road and I would like to curve it smoothly without using arrays.
I have it subdivided. Any ideas of how should I do it? Check the image below of my road and below that image you will see copy from internet of how I want it to look like:

[image]

Internet copy:

[image]

**P.S.** I forgot to say that I would like to do something so the road wouldn't have a lot of subdivision. What I mean is that I want it to be 1 solid road without any pieces that it is made up with. Because each time I upload it to software one of the faces goes invisible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a ***Spin Tool***.
[image]

Snap the cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*) to the bottom vertex of your plane, select the edge and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to spin it. Play with the settings in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>)- change the *Center* X position to make the curved part of the mesh longer.
[image]

Continue modeling using *spin tool* and close the road (*remove doubles* when finish).
[image]

### TEXTURING

Select one edge in the middle of the mesh, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Mark Seam*. Enable *Face selection mode*, select the whole mesh, then unselect and reselect one of the faces. Press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Follow Active Quads*-->*OK*. Change the *viewport shading* to ***Textured***.
[image]

Go to *UV Editor* and scale the *UV island* to fit the pattern scale as you like.
[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. I did not know that you can do it from any vertex, I was always selecting everything because I thought it would break the mesh.

Comment: How do you apply texture to the mesh? When I export it to fbx its never there.